# Disk not resized after resizing Ubuntu Server in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I recently needed to resize an Ubuntu Server Image for VirtualBox.

Host OS is also Ubuntu. vboxmanage modifyhd ran fine and then I booted the client VM on VirtualBox using a live image.

Ran gparted to resize the partition to use the increased available space.

At this stage everything looks fine.

However when I restart the VM and try and install a package I get an error not enough space.

Running df -h and fdisk -l give the following output

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved running lvextend followed by fsadm resize fixed the problem

[image: Commands]